# Adding Reference Confusion in VS 2010 on 64 bit machine

Tags: asp.net, reference

In a 64 bit machine, When I am trying to add the reference through Visual Studio 2010, by right clicking and say add Reference it shows all the dlls with path:

```
C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\ReferenceAssembles\MicrosoftFramework\.NetFramework\
```

How can I change the path, so that It can use `C:\ProgramFiles` instead of `C:\ProgramFiles (x86)`

I believe X86 means 32 bit, so it contains all the 32 bit dlls, but I need the 64 bit dlls to be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Those assemblies aren't actually used and unless your program *specifically* must be compiled against 32 or 64 bit (for instance because of interop with other dlls that are specifically compiled as say 32 bit) then don't worry about it. Those are usually actually just files to 'reference' but arent the ones your program uses. They just get some information from them but at run time refer to the gac and will compile based on 32/64 bit system or settings. So if I run on a 32 bit iis, my program will work. If I run on 64 bit - my same program will run as 64 bit.

See

"Consider a .NET application that is 100% type safe code. In this scenario it is possible to take your .NET executable that you run on your 32-bit machine and move it to the 64-bit system and have it run successfully. "

from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx

note - type safe is the key here.

Comment: Hi Adam,Thanks a bunch for the reply.But the problem is I need to add the 64 bit assembly rather than 32 bit assembly..When I am doing so I am getting the error..it could not load the assembly..I guess it has to look into GAC_64 folder..if it does so..the files are there..I don't know why it keeps on poping the same error.

Comment: How can I add the Oracle.Web.dll 64bit reference to the ASP.NET 4.0 website..please help me.

Comment: search your system for the oracle dll, and just browse for it and add it as a reference. When you add a ref to the gac, it really isn't going against the gac to find that list, just various locations listed in the registry.

Comment: I did add the Oracle.Web.dll from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.Web\v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342 but when I build the application it says, Error Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. I don't know what is happening at all..I am adding the file by browsing to the above location and it still says could not load assembly..Please help me out from this situation..Thanks a lot for your valuable replies.

Comment: I would search your system for this library - generally it will exist somewhere else on your system before being added to the gac. Add the reference from that location - try: ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\ASP.NET\Bin\2.x\   or   c:\Oracle\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.Web.dll Note the location referenced here: http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/nonsun/oracle/11.2.0.1.0/E11882_01/win.112/e12250/IntroInstallation.htm  (listed as: c:\Oracle\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.Web.dll)

Comment: I tried to add from there too..but it is still giving me the same error..When ever I say add reference it is adding an entry in the web.config file <add assembly="Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/> and it showing the error at that line.
    <add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>

Comment: @user788312: Are you sure the version 4.112.2.0 library is either installed in your GAC or in your /bin directory when running the application/site?

Comment: Also check out the other post on this I added for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279728/how-to-make-odp-net-4-0-64-bit-working-on-64-bit-machine-windows-7/6336663#6336663